# To align the background image to center and not stetched : in java code ANDROID (not manifest)

Tags: android

I'm new to android development.

I'm trying to set background to my app by using this line of code

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.my_imagename);
```

That works perfectly. But the problem is the image appears stretched. What should I do to make it align in the center (exactly like original image) and not stretched.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: try to set background in `layout` file

Comment: add this attribute to imageView in xml like scaleType ="center"

Comment: Would like to know how it is done in Java, rather than in XML file. I think there is a way to do it in the code Isn't it. ? Would be of help if you know anything in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use xml layout for the background image:

```
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/fm_id"
  android:layout_width="img_width"
  android:layout_height="img_height"
  ... ...
  >

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/my_imagename"

    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Hope this help

Comment: Would like to know how it is done in Java, rather than in XML file. I think there is a way to do it in the code Isn't it. ? Would be of help if you know anything in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

Use an ImageView to store the background and instead of `setBackgroundDrawableResource()` use `setImageDrawable()`. This sets the `android:src` attribute instead of the `android:background` attribute. 
Now you can set the scale type:

```
android:scaleType = "centerInside";
```

Check the ImageView api for other [scale types.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) 
If you really need to edit the scale from java (as your question implies) you can use the `setScaleType()` method for ImageViews:

```
view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```